# What's the right way to purge recursively with apt?

Tags: debian, apt

I've just realised I'm not sure how to perform a purge with Apt, that will purge all the dependencies too. I'm reading here and there and still unsure have these candidates:

```
apt purge --auto-remove <packagename>
```

and (after purging some packages first):

```
apt autoremove --purge
```

Are they correct? Equivalent? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They’re both correct, but not quite equivalent.

```
apt purge --auto-remove <packagename>
```

purges `packagename` and any packages which are rendered unnecessary by its removal, as well as any other packages which aren’t necessary.

```
apt autoremove --purge
```

purges any packages which aren’t necessary (marked as “automatically installed” and with no dependent packages).

The first form is what you’d use when manipulating individual packages; the latter is a clean-up operation across all packages.

You could also enable `APT::Get::AutomaticRemove` in your `apt` configuration to get `apt` to always auto-remove (or use `aptitude` which behaves like that by default).

Answer (score 0):

The OP's suggested commands and the [existing answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/522487/85414) are correct, particularly according to the man page, but it turns out `apt`'s behaviour is slightly more flexible than the documentation suggests.

To make the command line more concise when removing a package and its automatically installed dependencies, you *can* supply a package name to the autoremove command, as in `apt autoremove <pkg>`, in which case it behaves as `apt remove --autoremove <pkg>`. Thus, `apt autoremove --purge <pkg>` and `apt purge --autoremove <pkg>` both produce the same result.

Going further, `apt autopurge <pkg>` behaves in the same way as the canonical form `apt remove --purge --autoremove <pkg>`, and seems to be the most concise way to achieve recursive purging.

Whether or not to document this behaviour has apparently [been controversial](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/merge_requests/263) among the developers.